# Cannot receive or send email from my email server (iRedMail) what do I do?

Tags: server, 13.04, email

#### ---System---

Acer Aspire One ZG5
CPU: Intel Atom N270
GPU: Intel 945GSE
RAM: 1.5 Gb
Swap: 1.5 Gb
Storage: 120 Gb
OS: Ubuntu 13.04 Raring 32bit

Hi,

I set up iRedMail for my email server however port 25 is blocked by my ISP thus I cannot receive or send email from my server. I'm not sure if this is the main reason, I believe it is. I figured I could use a smart host to send email but as for receiving email I don't know. Anyone know how I would get around this?

Comment: Are you sure your ISP blocks **incoming** SMTP connections too?

Comment: a test email from google failed resulting in a time out

Comment: oh btw google's gmail is only sending to port 25 for whatever reason, it's ignoring any other possible ports

Comment: Set up your email server to use port 2525. It's an alt port that is commonly used. See if that works. Is your next downstream SMTP server Google Gmail? If so, find out what alternate ports they use.